# How to disable the Text field name is disappearing when we moved out the input filed box in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have made autocomplete features using Downshift using react js. But the problem is when I am searching for something its input field value is disappearing when I click on the outside. Here is the sample code.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Highlighter from "react-highlight-words";
import Downshift from "downshift";
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [names, setnames] = useState([{

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
  const [movie, setmovie] = useState([])
   fetchMovies = fetchMovies.bind(this);
   inputOnChange = inputOnChange.bind(this);

  function inputOnChange(event) {
    if (!event.target.value) {
      return;
    }
    fetchMovies(event.target.value);
  }

  function downshiftOnChange(selectedMovie) {
    alert(`your favourite movie is ${selectedMovie.title}`);
  }

  function fetchMovies(movie) {
    const moviesURL = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=1b5adf76a72a13bad99b8fc0c68cb085&query=${movie}`;
    axios.get(moviesURL).then(response => {
      setmovie(response.data.results);
      // this.setState({ movies: response.data.results });
    });
  }
  return (
            <Downshift
        onChange={downshiftOnChange}
        itemToString={item => (item ? item.title : "")}
      >
        {({
          selectedItem,
          getInputProps,
          getItemProps,
          highlightedIndex,
          isOpen,
          inputValue,
          getLabelProps
        }) => (
          <div>
            <label
              style={{ marginTop: "1rem", display: "block" }}
              {...getLabelProps()}
            >
              Choose your favourite movie
            </label>{" "}
            <br />
            <input
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: "Search movies",
                onChange: inputOnChange
              })}
            />
            {isOpen ? (
              <div className="downshift-dropdown">
                {movie
                  .filter(
                    item =>
                      !inputValue ||
                      item.title
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
                  )
                  .slice(0, 10)
                  .map((item, index) => (
                    <div
                      className="dropdown-item"
                      {...getItemProps({ key: index, index, item })}
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor:
                          highlightedIndex === index ? "lightgray" : "white",
                        fontWeight: selectedItem === item ? "bold" : "normal"
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.title}
                    </div>
                  ))}
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        )}
      </Downshift>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the sample code I have written. Also, when I click shift+home, it is also not working.

Problem 1: when the user clicked the outside text field value whatever I searched this is disappearing.

Problem 2: shift + home is not working also.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

> when the user clicked the outside text field value whatever I searched this is disappearing.

One way you could do it is to set the [`stateReducer`](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift#statereducer) on the `Downshift` component:

> This function will be called each time downshift sets its internal state (or calls your onStateChange handler for control props). It allows you to modify the state change that will take place which can give you fine grain control over how the component interacts with user updates without having to use Control Props. It gives you the current state and the state that will be set, and you return the state that you want to set.

> state: The full current state of downshift.

> changes: These are the properties that are about to change. This also has a type property which you can learn more about in the stateChangeTypes section.

```
function stateReducer(state, changes) {
  switch (changes.type) {
    case Downshift.stateChangeTypes.mouseUp:
      return {
        ...changes,
        isOpen: true,
        inputValue: state.inputValue,
      };
    default:
      return changes;
  }
}
```

This way if you click outside the text field the dropdown will stay open and the input value won't be reset.

For a list of all state change types see the documentation [here](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift#statechangetypes)

You might also be able to get something working using the `onBlur` prop on the `input`, but I didn't get that working.